# How to dynamically generate input for a celery chord (map-reduce) task

Tags: python, mapreduce, celery

I'm using celery to process documents using a workflow I've managed to model as a map-reduce task, see schematic below for an overview. Most examples in the docs show how to use groups and chords to implement workflows, but in all of those examples, the 'generator' step is cheap and can be executed synchronously [[link](https://celery.readthedocs.io/en/latest/userguide/canvas.html#groups)].

In my case, it's a very expensive operation that I would rather be done in the background.

Here's a small snippet exemplifying my setup - link to repo with associated docker-compose to set up rabbitmq/postgres [[here](https://github.com/cbcoutinho/celery-map-reduce)]:

```py
# tasks.py

import os
import time
import celery
from celery import group, chord
from celery.utils.log import get_task_logger


app = celery.Celery(
    __name__,
    broker="amqp://{user}:{password}@{host}".format(
        user="guest", password="guest", host=os.getenv("RABBIT", "localhost"), vhost=""
    ),
    backend="db+postgresql+psycopg2://{user}:{password}@{host}/{database}".format(
        user="postgres",
        password="postgres",
        host=os.getenv("PGHOST", "localhost"),
        database="postgres",
    ),
)

logger = get_task_logger(__name__)


@app.task()
def gen(n):
    """ Expensive generator function """
    time.sleep(10)
    return list(range(n))


@app.task()
def multiply(x):
    """ Function used by the mapper """
    return x * x


@app.task()
def reducer(numbers):
    """ Simple reduce function """
    time.sleep(10)
    return sum(numbers)


@app.task()
def map_reduce(n):
    """ Takes input that dynamically produces a generator that in turn, produce
    input to a map-reduce job """

    numbers = gen.s(n)
    my_chord = chord(group(multiply.s(n) for n in numbers()), reducer.s())
    result = my_chord()

    return result
```

Ideally, I'd like to be able to call the `map_reduce` function asynchronously and get back the result of the chord in the same task, but the closest I've gotten is by analyzing the task created by the parsing task:

```py
>>> from tasks import map_reduce
>>> task = map_reduce.apply_async(args=(10,))
>>> task.get()
(('dc2c36d4-c4ca-4032-a1a2-a4c90d78d7fe',
  (('805d55fa-03a2-43f1-884c-97f58241bf3b', None),
   [(('da0cb921-914a-4e5b-bc8b-b8c5dd6df050', None), None),
    (('3f808f4b-777f-45bf-86a9-b3a5747d0d55', None), None),
    (('fa3e15ee-7aa6-44ca-8138-664d332d5d63', None), None),
    (('5c349280-9e0c-40bb-94b5-057605cf5c56', None), None),
    (('88a1f18d-83fe-40c5-bbd1-00cc781ca7be', None), None),
    (('1b027655-3065-4e15-aa46-8cb3e1f8afaf', None), None),
    (('7813cab2-cbd4-4fe9-b7e2-8f0bf5399a32', None), None),
    (('e1539d2a-2bd5-4df3-83a3-b11500c610c4', None), None),
    (('919c52a8-102b-4ceb-89fb-bcbc7f1c98ab', None), None),
    (('19fcfd0d-3799-4f97-8c29-86451a9da3f5', None), None)])),
 None)
>>> celery.result.AsyncResult(task.get()[0][0]).get()
285
```

Is there a better way to link the two tasks together, so that the returned result from map_reduce is the result of the chord based on a dynamically generated input?

[image: Schematic workflow]

Answer (score 0):

you can use AsyncResult class https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/reference/celery.result.html

```
task_id = task.get()[0][0]
print(celery.result.AsyncResult(task_id).get())
```

Comment: thanks for the tip, I think that's similar to what I'm already doing. This still splits up the task into two parts though, which I'm trying to avoid.